# Not able to installl mysql-server ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-10.04

I'm not able to install mysql-server on ubuntu 10.04
I had installed mysql but it was giving this error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

So I removed mysql-server completely from synaptic
but after this i'm not able to reinstall it. When I try to reinstall it synaptic freezes.

how to do remove each file of mysql and install it ?

Comment: `apt-get purge mysql-server`, should remove everything, config files included.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to use the command line interface. So, I use `apt-get` to remove/install packages.

You can try removing mysql server including configuration files

```
$ sudo apt-get --force-yes purge mysql-server
```

You can then try installing it

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: I tried to install from apt-get but the installation process stops at  "Setting up mysql-server-5.1 (5.1.41-3ubuntu12.8) ..."

Comment: Do you mean it just hanged? Is there any error message?

Comment: no error message I put terminal for 30 min, and then killed the session.